# Enable ChromeDriver Log and path update Path in Robot Framework

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

Can anyone help me please with passing the service_arg --log-path to ChromeDriver in order to enable and control the path of the driver log in RobotFramework. When i am trying to pass the service arguments i start receiving errors.

I will post two Tests that have similar structure.[`Chrome Log Tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZivgP.png)

[image: 1]: [enter image description here]

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library  
Library    OperatingSystem
Library    Collections        
                   
*** Variables ***

${URL}    https://google.com
${Browser}    Chrome
${path}    D:\\Users\\x\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\Scripts\\chromedriver.exe
${chromelogs}    D:\\Users\\x\\eclipse-workspace\\ChromeOptions\\jpg 
                           
      
*** Test Cases ***

Test 001
    [Documentation]     ChromeLog path

    Create Webdriver    ${Browser}    executable_path=${path}    service_args=["--log-path=${chromelogs}"]
    Go To    ${URL}
    [Teardown]    Close All Browsers
    
Test 002
    [Documentation]     Chrome options
         
    ${chrome_options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys   
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    version                 
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    disable-infobars
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    start-maximized     
    
    Create Webdriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${chrome_options}    executable_path=${path}    service_args=["--log-path=${chromelogs}"]             
    Go To   ${URL}       
    [Teardown]    Close All Browsers
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternate way to capture chromedriver logs that will solve your problem for debugging.

1. Open chromedriver.exe from the command line (chromedriver.exe --verbose --log-path=C:\chromedriver.log, it will listen on port 9551)
2. Use sample code
   Open Browser    http://vpatel.rf.gd   gc    None    http://localhost:9515
   Click element   id=alertbtn

chrome will show requires logs on command windows on step1. if you happen to find a way to puts logging in code then do share here.

-Vinay

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of SeleniumLibrary include service_log_path argument.
https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Open%20Browser

Open Browser  ${LOGIN URL}  ${BROWSER}  service_log_path=webdriver.log

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make Robot Framework `Selenium2Library` library log Chrome console by modifying the `WebDriver` creation that way:

```
# Create the ChromeOptions
${options}=  Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()  sys, selenium.webdriver

# Add the --log-file command line switch thanks to https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities + https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches
Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    log-file\=/tmp/chrome.log

# Add other command line arguments if required like "proxy-server" or "no-sandbox"
#Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    [...]

# Create the WebDriver
Create WebDriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${options}
```

This way, you will have the Chrome logs appended in file `/tmp/chrome.log`.

In my case, as I was in a bash script and wanted to display the logs in the standard output as the tests were executed, I added the following line in my script:

```
tail -F /tmp/chrome.log &
```